# Reverse filter in jQuery

Tags: jquery

Instead of this...

```
$("#gridContainerAvailable input:checkbox")
```

How do I do this...

```
var parent = $("#gridContainerAvailable");

parent.[insert method here].('input:checkbox')
```

Cheers, Ian.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also do it like:

```
$("input:checkbox", "#gridContainerAvailable")
```

if thats what you're thinking or the find method

```
parent.find("input:checkbox");
```

Comment: Do you think the first method is faster than the second?

Comment: you probaly wont see a big difference, but for readability, pick the first.

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
var parent = $("#gridContainerAvailable");

parent.find('input:checkbox')
```

but i see no reason in doing that as i think that

```
 $("#gridContainerAvailable input:checkbox")
```

it's much faster

Comment: For sure, but the parent is to be a parameter. I've got it working with string concatenation at the moment but I think its cleaner calling a method.

Comment: @IanWarburton yes, it's cleaner and if you have no performance problems it's perfectly ok to do that